# UIWebView doesn't reload image file from Documents folder

Tags: javascript, html, swift, uiwebview

I'm using [RichEditorView](https://github.com/cjwirth/RichEditorView) as editor for a note taking app. so the note's text is in html.  When I insert images selected from the camera roll, they all appear (see screenshot below). However, when I stop the simulator and restart the app, the image cannot be found.
I made sure the image file is in the Documents folder.

didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo looks like this

```
 if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

            if let imageData = pickedImage.resizeImage(200.0 , maxWidth:300.0, compression:0.7) {
```

let filename = NSUUID().UUIDString + ".jpg"

let fileURL = getDocumentsURL().URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename)

print("file url: (fileURL)")

do {
try imageData.writeToURL(fileURL, options: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingAtomic)
   }
catch let error as NSError  {

print(error)
 // this is a function from [RichEditorView](https://github.com/cjwirth/RichEditorView)              self.keyboardToolbar.editor?.insertImage(fileURL.absoluteString, alt: "new image")
 dismissViewControllerAnimated(true , completion: nil)

Writing the file is successful, no error is thrown - otherwise it couldn't be retrieved again and wouldn't display.

See the screenshots below. The image tag in the html looks like this

```
<img src="file:///Users/Dominik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BC19750C-FE45-4C7A-853E-1933DE0B5515/data/Containers/Data/Application/6F3EFBA9-E1CA-45F7-9567-D5E653972DB6/Documents/3E9BCE98-033D-4754-9125-683F704E2CEA.jpg" alt="image">
```

the note text (in html) is persisted in Core Data. so after closing the app it is reloaded. the img tag is still in the text and the image should be loaded.. but it doesn't load.

Thank you for any hints ...

[image: html loads the image from the document folder]

[image: After reloading the app in Xcode, the image cannot be found]

Comment: Would you create fiddle for this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gruentee/k809v79r/#&togetherjs=lyx2KDTprs thanks for looking into this. However, the js and html are probably not the problem. RichtEditorView is written in Swift and the code executes js commands and listens to return values from the js executed in the UIWebView.